# How to speed up database synchronization?

Tags: stellar-core

After stellar-core synchronization DB filling began.
At a rate of approximately 1.5% per day (

It can affect database synchronization speed?
Can it be possible to use a snapshot of the base?

===========================================================================

Environment

- Windows > WSL > Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- PostgreSQL on Windows

Used this instruction https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/f05491a79c45606285a9b76096ce6f3880ba5b9e/docs/quickstart.md

my "stellar-core.cfg"

```
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"

LOG_FILE_PATH="/var/log/stellar/stellar-core.log"
BUCKET_DIR_PATH="/var/lib/stellar/buckets"

#DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar user=stellar"
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar user=stellar password=7uo552u host=172.17.160.1"

CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true
#CATCHUP_RECENT=1024

UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
FAILURE_SAFETY=1

[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="www.stellar.org"
QUALITY="HIGH"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_1"
HOME_DOMAIN="www.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH"
ADDRESS="core-live-a.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_2"
HOME_DOMAIN="www.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK"
ADDRESS="core-live-b.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_3"
HOME_DOMAIN="www.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ"
ADDRESS="core-live-c.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to sync to the current state of the network you should not specify `CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true` and instead set that to false. The configuration that you used is to setup full nodes that verify the entire history from genesis (useful when setting up Horizon nodes that understand all of history).